# Python hash with if cases

Tags: python, hash, set, hashtable

I have a question regarding the **hash**(self) function of Python.

So in my method I have the following code pieces

```
def __init__(self, upper1, lower1, upper2, lower2):
    self.phase = 1
    self.gammas = frozenset()
    self.gammabars = frozenset()

def __hash__(self):
    if self.gammas:
        return hash(self.gammas)
    elif self.gammabars:
        return hash(self.gammabars)
```

So I want to say:

If self.gammas is not empty, then return the hashvalue of self.gammas or self.gammabars etc.

But if I now start my program, I get:

```
TypeError: __hash__ method should return an integer
```

So do you know, how to fix that?

Comment: Please show all code required to run your program and reproduce the problem.

Comment: @KlausD. Hm the problem is, the code is quite long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the hash of a tuple method:

```
return hash((self.gammas, self.gammabar))
```

Comment: But I do not have a tuple with gammas AND gammabars inside.

Comment: That doesn't matter you return the hash of the tuple.

Comment: Ah, please notes, return `hash((self.gammas, self.gammabar))` will cause some unexpected result. E.g., if `self.gammas` is `not empty`, in question, @Armani42 want to return `hash(self.gammas)`. Most time it does not have any problem, however, some special cases, imagine if self.gammas is the same, but self.gammabars has been changed, `hash((self.gammas, self.gammabars))` will become to different. But in this case, it should be the same.

Answer (score 3):

When you called `hash(instance)`, both of your `self.gammas` or `self.gammabars` cannot be `True`. You can try add an else case:

```
def __hash__(self):
    if self.gammas:
        return hash(self.gammas)
    elif self.gammabars:
        return hash(self.gammabars)
    else:
        return hash(something)
        # or
        raise ValueError('gammas and gammabars are not valid.')
```

or debug your code to confirm the `self.gammas` and `self.gammabars` value.

Comment: Hmm thanks, so if I add if self.gammas != {}: return hash(self.gammas) it works. But strange, that it does not work in the other way around.

Comment: @Armani42 What do you mean `in the other way around`? Can you give me an example?

Comment: And please note, `dict` is unhashable. So hash(dict_instance) will raise `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`

Comment: Yeah so if I say if self.gammas: I get the error and if i say the != {} then it works, I really don't know why...

Comment: @Armani42 Oh I see. If your condition is `if self.gammas != {}`, that means `frozenset() != dict()`, if it is an empty frozenset, the result is True. But if your condition is `if self.gammas`, that means `bool(frozenset())`, if it is an empty frozenset, the result is False. You can test it by: `print(frozenset() != {})
` `print(bool(frozenset()))`

Comment: @Armani42 That means, even though `self.gammas` is an empty frozenset, the stream will still go into the first condition block, it will never go into the second condition block.

Comment: Thanks! :) So how can I program it the way that I just say if self.gammas is not an empty frozenset()?

Comment: `self.gammas != frozenset()` or `self.gammas is not frozenset()`